# XAMPP,Apache - Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: apache, http, xampp

I got the same error of shutdown unexpectedly. I tried everything.

1. I uninstalled skype.
2. I tried changing the ports to 81,444 / 81,443 / 88/443 / 80,443(default).
3. I went to services and tried killing required one.
4. I went to windows firewall and created the new inbound rule too.
5. I uninstalled old apache and installed new one too. This worked for 1 day.
6. I checked whether the port 80 is busy or not but none of the services is using port
   80,443. I used netstat -a command to check all the list of port for Win-8.
7. I tried stopping windows http services by "NET STOP HTTP".
8. I unchecked "Internet Information Services" from program and features.
9. I checked "Resource Monitor" for port usage. Port 80 is being used by HTTP server only 
   but not responding to xampp control panel.

In all of the above cases, I made the changes and restarted the laptop every time to take the effect. But nothing has worked. Each time i got the same error i.e "XAMPP, Apache - Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly".

Please give me the solution for this error. I am very much frustrated now. Please help me. Any help would be appreciable. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you enable Apache Logs in debug mode.

```
LogLevel debug
```

Also you can get easily notified for syntax issues with help of below command.

```
httpd -t
```

Comment: Thanks @KNOWARTH..

I am using latest version of apache. And i think, whatever you are suggesting is already their. It gives you the exact error log.

However my problem is port. My system is not using port 80 or 443 but apache giving me the error, port is busy and unexpected shutdown. How do i reset or reassign that port for apache.(even though that port is used by any service).

Answer (score 0):

For your skype, go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> connection. Disable the "Use port 80 and 443 for alternatives for incoming connections"

Sign Out and Close all Skype windows. Try restart your Apache again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error appeared after I changed the external drive on which I saved my projects. Previously it was F: and now it is G:. But in the httpd-vhosts.conf file I forgot to change the virtual host path. After changing to G: in the httpd-vhosts.conf file, XAMPP started working.
Or when the computer had too few resources, e.g. RAM.